# Dafny: no terms found to trigger on and a consequent assertion error

Tags: dafny

This is the code that I wrote for a method that returns the maximum of two integers:

```
predicate greater(x: int, a: int, b: int){
    (x >= a) && (x >= b)
}

method Max(a: int, b: int) returns (max: int)
    ensures max >= a
    ensures max >= b
    ensures forall x /*{:trigger greater(x,a,b)}*/ :: (greater(x,a,b)) ==> x >= max
{
    if (a > b){
        max := a;
    }else{
        max := b;
    }
//  assert greater(max, a, b); - trivial assertion
}

method Main(){
    var res:= Max(4, 5);

    assert res == 5;
}
```

As you can see, I have tried both the two techniques metnioned in the [Wiki page](https://github.com/dafny-lang/dafny/wiki/FAQ#how-does-dafny-handle-quantifiers-ive-heard-about-triggers-what-are-those) (manual trigger assignment and also adding a trivial non-useful assertion in the method body. However, I still get an assertion error.

I am not sure what else to do. I have read other answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49649019/dafny-no-terms-to-trigger-on-predicate), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50195891/how-do-i-write-a-clean-function-in-dafny-to-get-the-minimum-of-a-set) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36404463/dafny-no-terms-found-to-trigger-on-error-message), but none have helped me so far.

PS: I know there is a simpler way to write the postconditions for this particular method, however, I really wish to model the postconditions in terms of the forall quantifier only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's forget `greater` for a while and just take a look at what you're trying to achieve. After the call to `Max` in `Main`, you know the following (from the postcondition of `Max`):

```
res >= 4
res >= 5
forall x :: x >= 4 && x >= 5 ==> x >= res
```

You're trying to prove `res == 5` from this. The second of these three things immediately gives you half of that equality, so all you need to do is obtain `5 >= res`. If you instantiate the quantifier with `5` for `x`, you will get

```
5 >= 4 && 5 >= 4 ==> 5 >= res
```

which simplifies to `5 >= res`, which is what you need, so that's the end of your proof.

In summary, the proof comes down to instantiating the quantifier with `5` for `x`. Next, you need to know a little about how the Dafny verifier instantiates quantifiers. Essentially, it does this by looking at the "shape" of the quantifier and looking for similar things in the context of what you're trying to prove. By "shape", I mean things like "the functions and predicates it uses". Usually, this technique works well, but in your case, the quantifier is so plain that it doesn't have any "shape" to speak of. Consequently, the verifier fails to come up with the needed instantiation.

It would be nice if we could just say "hey, try instantiating that quantifier with `5` for `x`". Well, we can, if we give the quantifier some "shape" that we can refer to. That's what those wiki and other guidelines are trying to say. This is where it's useful to introduce the predicate `greater`. (Don't try to manually write trigger annotations.)

Alright, after introducing `greater`, your specification says

```
ensures greater(max, a, b)
ensures forall x :: greater(x, a, b) ==> x >= max
```

This says "`max` satisfies `greater(max, a, b)`" and "among *all* values `x` that satisfy `greater(x, a, b)`, `max` is the smallest". After the call to `Max` in `Main`, we then have:

```
greater(res, 4, 5)
forall x :: greater(x, 4, 5) ==> x >= res
```

Recall, I said the verifier tries to figure out quantifier instantiations by looking at the quantifier and looking at the context around your assertion, and you're trying to instantiate the quantifier with `5` for `x`. So, if you can add something to the context just before the assertion that tempts the verifier to do that instantiation, then you're done.

Here's the answer: you want to introduce the term `greater(5, 4, 5)`. This has a shape much like the `greater(x, 4, 5)` in the quantifier. Because of this similarity, the verifier will instantiate `x` with `5`, which gives

```
greater(5, 4, 5) ==> 5 >= res
```

And since `greater(5, 4, 5)` is easily proved to be `true`, the needed fact `5 >= res` follows.

So, change the body of `Main` to

```
var res := Max(4, 5);
assert greater(5, 4, 5);
assert res == 5;
```

and you're done. The verifier will prove the both assertions. The first is trivial, and after proving it, the verifier gets to use the term `greater(5, 4, 5)` in the proof of the second assertion. That term is what triggers the quantifier, which produces the fact `5 >= res`, which proves the second assertion.

I want to point out that most quantifiers we try to prove *do* have some shape already. In your case, the predicate `greater` was introduced in order to give some shape to the quantifier. The technique of adding the extra assertion (here, `assert greater(5, 4, 5)`) is the same whether or not `greater` was already defined or was introduced as a trivial predicate that provides shape.